# How to make a part of jpg clickable in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzr32.jpg)

As in the example image. I want to use this image as background and I want a portion of the image like building and towers clickable to open a new activity in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by mapping the image and comparing the click with the rect areas mapped from your image.

After mapped (probably directly on your code) you will have your onClickListener like this:

```
public void onClick(MotionEvent v){
     for(Pair<Rect,ActionListener> areas : mappedAreas)
            if(areas.first.contains(v))
                   areas.second.onClick(v);
}
```

PS: You will have problems with absolute values on different screen sizes (if the component allows fit_screen) then you should map as relative coordinates (percentage) and convert it to absolute values before comparing.